Run Airflow DockerOperator for list of names with parallel running of 5
I have a list of scrapy spiders which run inside Docker (more than 50). I want to have one dag that goes through that spiders' list and runs no more than 5 docker containers in parallel. What I've done (and it didn't work at all):
    @dag(
        dag_id='run_spiders',
        default_args=default_args,
        catchup=False
    )
    def processing_spiders():
    
        list_of_spiders = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    
        @task
        def run_docker_container(spider_name):
            t1 = DockerOperator(
                api_version='auto',
                ...,
                command=f'python3 ./main.py -tn={spider_name}',
                auto_remove='force',
                force_pull=True,
                task_id=f'run_{spider_name}_crawler',
                environment=...,
                tty=True,
                container_name=f'{spider_name}_crawler',
                timeout=180
            )
    
            t1
    
        for spider in list_of_spiders:
            run_docker_container(spider)
    
    
    processing_think_tanks()

I couldn't even run these three spiders one after another not to mention parallelism. So I'd be very grateful for help. Thanks in advance!

which scheduler?
